# CSS text of dropdown to display lighter

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I need to display the text of dropdown list as lighter ..  Below is my code:

```
   <div>
                @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Change --")
                <button class="btn primary-bg" style="margin-right: 30px;" title="Status Change" onclick="ChangeMultiStatus(); return false;">Multi-Status</button>
        </div>
```

Below is what I have and what I expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some opacity by adding `opacity: 0.6;` to your style tag.

```
<div>
  @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Change --")
  <button class="btn primary-bg" style="margin-right: 30px; opacity: 0.6;" title="Status Change" onclick="ChangeMultiStatus(); return false;">Multi-Status</button>
</div>
```

Change the opacity value as you wish.

Comment: I don't want to change my .css file how can I add style in dorpdownlist in above code.

Comment: You don't need to. You're using inline styling in your piece of code. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can give color(preferable) or opacity css to particular dropdown element.